# bubble sort in python:index out of range

Tags: python

I am new to python and I was trying out bubble sort. Not able to find the error.
Little help here.

```
def bubble(n, list):
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
            if list[j] > list[j + 1]:
                list[j],list[j+1] = list[j + 1],list[j]

def main():
    n = input('size')
    n = int(n)
    list = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        no = input('no')
        list + [no]
    bubble(n, list)
    print(list)

main()
```

During execution, it's showing:
line 4, in bubble
if (list[j] > list[j + 1]):
IndexError: list index out of range

But I couldn't find out how. The index always will be

Comment: Try `for i in range(0, n - 1):`

Comment: `list + [no]` is doing nothing. Your list is **empty**.

Comment: Dont use `list` as a variable name. It is a keyword argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you don't convert the `input('no')` to `int`. It is not the cause of the current problem, but would cause problems later.

The second problem is that you use `list` as a variable name. `list` is a predefined Python class and you will overwrite it. Choose a different name.

The third problem is that you use `list + [no]`. That will not add `no` to `list`. It would just store the output temporarily and delete it automatically. There are 2 solutions:
1. Using `+=`
`a += b` is equal to `a = a + b`. This is also the case for many arithmetical operators. Just replace `+` with `+=`.
2. Using `append`
`append` is faster. Use it like `somelist.append(somevalue)`.